# FInding Electric FIeld of a System Containing a Dielectric Shell At the Origin and a Charge At Any Location

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, field-theory, dielectric

So this problem would be (relatively) easy if the charge was only in the center, but because it can be at any distance from the origin, I am not sure how the electric field behaves.

From what I have been able to gather, If the charge was in the center, then the charge inside/outside the shell would be the same as if there was no dialectic. But in the shell itself, this is altered by a factor of 1/k. This gives me the hunch that the field would not depend on h if the charge was not in the "crust" of the shell, but I have an even greater hunch that this isn't the case due to how I've seen fields outside dielectric *spheres* behave.

Unfortunately, I don't have a textbook / concrete resource for this and I don't know how to solve this. I also can't find any similar problems via google - only the simplified case where the charge is exactly in the center.

I've attached an image of the exact problem containing everything I'm given. All help is appreciated, thanks!

[image: Exact Problem]